# iphone over the air in house distribution not downloading on devices via the web site

Tags: xcode, code-signing, enterprise, over-the-air

Setup everything looks good, certs, provisions, etc.  App starts to download and then get the message...

App could not be installed at this time.

Here is what we are getting on the console.

Everything looks good on the certs, etc.  AD HOC works fine.

Should the Enterprise Signed .IPA be able to drag and drop on iTunes like Ad-Hoc?  This also is not working....????

```
Jun 29 14:16:23 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-1349820530180162939/-5817434632371065835" requested by itunesstored
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 __MobileInstallationInstall_Server_block_invoke_0: Installing app [REMOVED]
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: Jun 29 14:16:24  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta lockdownd[28] <Error>: Jun 29 14:16:24  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted NonEmptySubject]
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta lockdownd[28] <Error>: Jun 29 14:16:24  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted NonEmptySubject]
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: entitlement 'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.drjhzr/foo_extracted/Payload/[REMOVED] 0xe8008016
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.drjhzr/foo_extracted/Payload/[REMOVED]
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta itunesstored[65] <Error>: 0x2fe93000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Jun 29 14:16:24 iPhone-4GS-IOS-60-Beta installd[30] <Error>: 0x2ffa6000 handle_install: API failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With enterprise / in house distribution, the release version has to be signed with the same profile as is used in the archive / distribution process.

Comment: Could you please tell more?

Comment: You can not sure a different (non-enterprise) signing either at the building / archiving point (the one you select in Xcode) and the distribution signing (the one for enterprise distribution after archiving) both signings have to be the same